# Process thread cannot sense the change of global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to test some process thread which will be ended with flag variable but it cannot sense the change of flag and continue infinite while loop.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep

flag = 1

def threadTest():
    while 1:
        if flag == 1:
            print('hi')
        else:
            break
        sleep(0.1)


def main():
    global flag
    thread = Process(target=threadTest)
    thread.start()
    sleep(5)
    flag = 0
    thread.join()
    print('thread exit')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is that any problem with my global variable declaration?

Comment: You do realize you use a process and not thread?

Comment: I know that if I use that code with thread not the process it works fine. But I have to use multi thread that works simultaneously not the single thread, so I take process and experiment what I prepare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually creating a Process, not a thread. **When creating a new Process, the state of main is "copied" to the new process and it is now independent from the main one.** So for that new process the flag is always 1.

simply `import threading` and change to:

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=threadTest)
```

And it should work.

I will also advise on changing `flag` to a boolean, as it is used as condition for a loop.

Comment: I know that if I use that code with thread not the process it works fine. But I have to use multi thread that works simultaneously not the single thread, so I take process and experiment what I prepare.

Comment: Still, multithread and Process are different things. I think you need to understand what exactly you want. If you want many threads, I will advise on using a [pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool)

Comment: I think the OP just figured out GIL in Python

Comment: I have to eliminate calculation time using multi thread but it cannot works because of the GIL policy in Python. So I choose the process and there is some test with global variable in the project. Thank you for your tip of Process principle.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use multiple processes and not threads, then there are multiple ways to communicate to the child process. One simple way would be to send a TERM signal to the child process and it should handle that appropriately. There are couple other options also like using SharedMemory etc.

Below is the modified code using the TERM signal.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
import signal

flag = 1

def exitHandler(signum, frame):
    global flag
    flag = 0
    print('Got the signal to stop. Flag set to 0.')


def threadTest():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exitHandler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exitHandler)
    while 1:
        if flag == 1:
            print('hi')
        else:
            print('Finally we are here!')
            break
        sleep(0.1)


def main():
    global flag
    process = Process(target=threadTest)
    process.start()
    print(process.pid)
    sleep(5)
    process.terminate()
    process.join()
    print('process exit')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```